# How to display content from sql database in specific order

Tags: css

i'm new to this (php & sql) , and i'm having a bit of a problem. Here it goes:

Content from database is displayed as block element , instead i want it to be inline displayed.

Here is the pic :https://i.stack.imgur.com/69VUe.jpg

and here is the code :

-style:

```
.article {
        width:300px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .article h2 {
        padding:10px;
        font-size:24px;
        text-align:right;
    }
    .article img {
        width:100%;
        margin:10px 0;
    }
    .article p {
        font-size:14px;
        text-align:justify;
    }
```

-php:

```
        <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","###","db-proba");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM article_1");
;



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class='article'>";
  echo "<h2>" . $row['naslov'] . "</h2>";
  ?>
  <img src="images/<?php echo $row['slika']; ?>" />
  <?php
  echo "<p>" . $row['tekst'] . "</p>";

  echo "</div>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried editing the CSS to `display:` them `inline;`?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not related to PHP or SQL – it is a CSS issue.

Whether an element is displayed as a block or inline depends on the `display` property.
You may set this one to `inline` or `inline-block`:

```
.article {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Another way of achieving a similar effect is to set the element to be a block element (which is the browser default for a `DIV`) and use floating. But floating is a bit more complicated in handling.

```
.article {
    float: left;
}
```

In either way you also have to specify the desired width. To get two, equal sized columns, each block needs a width of 50% to fill the whole width. Keep in mind that in the default box model, the width is measured for the content only – padding and borders are added. But nowadays you can change the box-model. A more complete solution might look like this:

```
.article-wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%; // shrink on small screens, i.e. make it fluid
}
.article {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
}
.article h2 {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    text-align: right;
}
.article img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.article p {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Related links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

```
.article {
   float: left;
}
```

Use [floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) to make your content sit side-by-side (here's a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D75Hb/)

Comment: Thanks for this , i've tried everything except that :) and it worked.

Comment: @user3283235 "everything", really? What about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)?

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
.article {
        width:300px;
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```